# Verwandle die Finalsätze in Präpositionalausdrücke

Tags: grammar

Kann mir bitte jemand zeigen, wie man den Satz verwandelt? Ich will meine Deutschübung machen, aber ich habe keine Ahnung, wie man die Aufgabe lösen kann. :)

Bsp.; Die Mutter nimmt ein Tuch, um die Fenster zu reinigen.

Comment: Was ist ein Präportionalausdruck?

Comment: Ich glaube er/sie meint Präpositionalphrase

Comment: Warum nicht "Präpositional*sätze*"? Es sollen doch ganze Sätze, nicht nur Phrasen oder Ausdrücke gebildet werden. Sonst wäre auch "bei der Fensterreinigung" eine korrekte Antwort.

Comment: @what: ist es doch auch... wo ist grammatikalisch der Unterschied zwischen "bei der Fensterreinigung" und "zwecks Reinigung der Fenster"? Beides ist eine Präpositionalphrase, einmal halt mit und einmal mit zwecks.

Comment: Die Mutter nimmt ein Tuch zum Behufe der Fensterreinigung. ;-)

Answer (score 4):

Die Mutter nimmt ein Tuch zwecks Reinigung der Fenster.

Comment: Laut Duden ist die Präposition _zwecks_ ein Wort der Amtssprache und sollte außerhalb dieses Bereiches nicht verwendet werden.

Answer (score 4):

Die Mutter nimmt zur Fensterreinigung ein Tuch.

Oder wenn du betonen willst, dass sie ein Tuch und z. B. keinen Lappen nimmt:
Die Mutter nimmt ein Tuch zur Fensterreinigung.

Comment: Ah, das ist natürlich eleganter als meine Antwort, aber die ist trotzdem besser, weil sie den finalen Sinn erhält ;-)

Answer (score 3):

Noch mehr Vorschläge:

> Die Mutter nimmt ein Tuch für die Fensterreinigung.
>
> Die Mutter nimmt ein Tuch zum Fensterreinigen.

Die Version von *what* mit **zwecks** ist aber schon wirklich sehr schön und trifft den Sinn am genauesten.

Comment: Genau das *zwecks* gefällt mir eben nicht, weil es sehr formal und gestelzt klingt.

Comment: Das ist sicher richtig, aber ich finde alle Prä.. konstruktionen zu diesem Beispiel künstlich und würde die um zu version bevorzugen. Wenn man wirklich genau analysiert, was gesagt wird, so ist zwecks aber am genauesten, denn es beantwortet die Frage "Warum, wozu nimmt sie ein Tuch?", genau wie auch die um-zu-Version während alle anderen Versionen von uns im wesentlichen "Was nimmt sie zur Fensterreinigung /für die...?" beantworten.

Comment: „Die Mutter nimmt ein Tuch zum Reinigen.“ –> „Die Mutter nimmt ein Tuch zum Fenster Reinigen.“ –> „ … zum Fensterreinigen.“ (Regeln 2006, §43). Oder vielleicht dann doch lieber „ … zur/für die Fensterreinigung.“, aber das passt dann nicht mehr zur Frage.

Comment: dann nehme ich Fensterreinigen :)

Comment: @ChristianGraf Es geht hier doch um das Verständnis der Grammatik, nicht um eine Stilübung.